WKWebview form filling with cross origin iframe
I’m working on an iOS app using WKWebView, and I have a specific use case involving cross-origin iframes and form autofill. I’m wondering if it’s possible to programmatically fill input elements, such as credit card numbers, within a cross-origin iframe loaded in a WKWebView.
I understand that due to the Same-Origin Policy, direct DOM manipulation of cross-origin iframes is restricted. However, I’m curious if there are any methods or workarounds that might allow me to achieve this, specifically within the context of WKWebView. Thanks.
